# ColorMaterial:AmbientAndDiffuse equivalent for CG\HLSL

Tags: unity, lighting

I have this shader written on shaderlab, which replaces Ambient and Diffuse values of the material, because I need to tweak vertices colors from the script.

```
Shader "VertexSimple"
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Pass 
        {
            ColorMaterial AmbientAndDiffuse
            Lighting Off

            SetTexture [_MainTex]
            {
                Combine texture * primary
            }
        }
    }
    Fallback "VertexLit"
}
```

I need to write an equivalent of this shader on CG\HLSL to do some other routines in it. Ideally it should be vertex\pixel shaders, not surface one. How can I do this?

Comment: I just don't know how to begin because I don't know how to write the ColorMaterial:AmbientAndDiffuse equvalent on CG.

Comment: I can help you with HLSL. This is the simplest PixelShader function you can have:
    `float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0  
    {  
       return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);  
    }`

this would output a red colour to any vertices you pass to the pixel shader. However I suggest you google vertex/pixel shader tutorial and either HLSL/CG and you'll get plenty of results.